# C# WPF image load like progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, image, performance, progress-bar

I'v a progressbar and an image.
When Progress Bar value is 50, image loaded by 50%.
I tried to add image as the progressbar foreground, but it have green shade. So ugly.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well color is all a matter of personal taste, I'm sure someone out there will like your groovy _green-shaded-picture-progress bar_.

Comment: @GaboO I am assuming that you want to use image which you are loading to be same as used in progressbar background.

Answer (score 0):

To run this sample, you need a snake image which you can get from http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/16/16242-illustration-of-a-green-snake-pv.png. I have used this url directly, but your should download image first and then use it.

1. You need a control template for your ProgressBar because you want to show percentage status too.
2. Otherwise normal ProgressBar would do.

Code can be used as is :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfControlTemplates._32794074.Win32794074"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Win32794074" Height="600" Width="1000">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="397*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="173*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="PBarCustom" Width="958" Height="200"  Maximum="958"  Value="958" Foreground="#FFE6E61F" Margin="17,185,17,11.932" ValueChanged="PBarCustom_ValueChanged">
            <ProgressBar.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/16/16242-illustration-of-a-green-snake-pv.png"/>
            </ProgressBar.Background>
            <ProgressBar.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Thumb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#FFC5EA1F" Stroke="#FF0DB442" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />

                        <Ellipse Fill="#FF7DEEDE" Height="124"  Stroke="#FF0DB442" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.3"/>
                        <Label x:Name="tbStatus" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="75" Foreground="#FF21BD76" Content="0"  />

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ProgressBar.Template>

        </ProgressBar>
        <Button x:Name="BtnLoadSnake" Content="Load Snake" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="462,14.068,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BtnLoadSnake_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfControlTemplates._32794074
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Win32794074.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Win32794074 : Window
    {
        public Win32794074()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        DispatcherTimer timer;
        private void BtnLoadSnake_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BtnLoadSnake.IsEnabled = false;
            PBarCustom.Value = PBarCustom.Maximum;
            Rectangle thumb = (Rectangle)PBarCustom.Template.FindName("Thumb", PBarCustom);
            thumb.Width = PBarCustom.Value;

            Label status = (Label)PBarCustom.Template.FindName("tbStatus", PBarCustom);
            status.Content = ((int)(100 - ((100 * PBarCustom.Value) / PBarCustom.Maximum))).ToString();

            Dispatcher disp = PBarCustom.Dispatcher;

            EventHandler pBarCallbackHandler = new EventHandler(pBarCallback);

            timer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), DispatcherPriority.Normal, pBarCallback, disp);            

        }

        private void pBarCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PBarCustom.Value -= 13;
            Rectangle thumb = (Rectangle)PBarCustom.Template.FindName("Thumb", PBarCustom);
            thumb.Width = PBarCustom.Value;

            Label status = (Label)PBarCustom.Template.FindName("tbStatus", PBarCustom);
            status.Content = ((int)(100 - ((100 * PBarCustom.Value) / PBarCustom.Maximum))).ToString();

            if (PBarCustom.Value == 0)
                timer.Stop();
        }

        private void PBarCustom_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {            
            if(e.NewValue == 0)
                BtnLoadSnake.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i had similar scenario.
if you want the scroll bar to be just a rectangle,
easiest way to make it:

1- add an image to your window.

2- put a grid on it in such a way that the grid hides the image.

3- programatically change the width or height of the grid.

tell me if you needed an example code.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i calculate with percent? (Used progressbar.maxvalue is about 100000)

Comment: the maximum value for a progress is 100. you should calculate the amount of your real work progress in percent and then set that value on progress bar.